# Using shell script to post a form

Tags: forms, shell, curl

I'm making a shell benchmarking script which posts it's results to a link.

The link will look like this:

```
http://hostname/upload.php?VAR1=1&VAR2=3&VAR3=something
```

I have done this:

```
curl http://hostname/upload.php?VAR1=$v1&VAR2=$v2&VAR3=$v3
```

But this does not work.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: What does it do that differs from what you expect it to do?

Comment: where's your form code ? please define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

The shell will put the current program in background due to the embedded `&`. To avoid that, just wrap the argument in double quotes, like this:

```
curl "http://hostname/upload.php?VAR1=$v1&VAR2=$v2&VAR3=$v3"
```